# Testing for string in file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 5K text file of vocabulary words (over 100,000 words, either in xls or txt file).  I only want to test if a given string exists in the text file using javascript / jquery.
1) Do I need a library function to do this?
2) Is the size of the file a problem in terms of performance?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: 1) Obviously no. (Libraries aren't magical. JavaScript libraries are written in JavaScript.) 2) It depends on the code.

Comment: See this: [read a large file into js](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/147336-fast-way-to-read-a-large-xml-file/) and this [js dict search](http://ejohn.org/blog/revised-javascript-dictionary-search/)

Comment: Thanks gibberish! Interesting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't tried anything yet or provided code, I'll give you a general layout and place to start.

1) [Get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) your data file via Ajax

2) Use `indexOf` or `match` to check for a match. Performance stats [here](http://jsperf.com/regexp-vs-indexof).

Comment: Thanks.  I guess 5K of text is not that big a deal in terms of loading.